# How to convert retrofit response into json object

Tags: android, json, post, retrofit

I just wanted to know that how could I convert this retrofit library response which is actually a JSON response to JSON object so I could use this in my android app to do something because I can not do anything with response in the buffered reader.

```
public void getMe(){
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
            .build();

    myApi api = adapter.create(myApi.class);
    api.sendme(

            userEmail,
            rs,
            Team1,
            Team2,

            new retrofit.Callback<retrofit.client.Response>() {
                @Override
                public void success(retrofit.client.Response result, retrofit.client.Response response) {

                    BufferedReader reader = null;


                    try {

                        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(result.getBody().in()));
                        if (!output.equals("")) {
                            output = reader.readLine();



                        }


                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    // loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Leaderboard.this, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    );


}
```

here get me is sending post response to the server

```
public interface myApi {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/myleaderboard.php")
void sendme(

        @Field("userEmail") String userEmail,
        @Field("rs") String rs,
        @Field("team1") String team1,
        @Field("team2") String team2,
        Callback<Response> callback);

 }
```

I m getting JSON response and I have to store that in my android code somehow whether that be using JSON object or anything else if possible.
please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the myAPi code to

```
public interface myApi {

@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/myleaderboard.php")
void sendme(

        @Field("userEmail") String userEmail,
        @Field("rs") String rs,
        @Field("team1") String team1,
        @Field("team2") String team2,
        Callback<JsonObject> callback);

 }
```

it will return JsonObject directly

Comment: ohk this looks promising let me check

Comment: i have made the required changes and my getme function now look like this

Comment: @Override
                    public void success(JSONObject jsonObject, retrofit.client.Response response) {

                        
                    }

Comment: yes in response it will return jsonobject directly , you can even get values from response like respone.getString("")

Comment: what do i need to do next to store that json response into an varibale for exmaple,  pls tell me as i am a newbie in android

Comment: ohk just let me implement these , i will gte back to u

Comment: this is what i have done   try {
                            String Name=  jsonObject.getString("name");
                            String Rank=  jsonObject.getString("rank");
                            String Accuracy=  jsonObject.getString("accuracy");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

Comment: this is my RestApi  looks like {"list":[{"name":"Ans","rank":"2","accuracy":"70"}]}      so will it work

Comment: yes it will work ...just do response.getJSONArray("list");.

Comment: actually i am trying many things but i think i am not able to find the right systax to do so,this is what i am doing                                       
    try {

                            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");
                             Name=  result.getJSONObject().getString()
                             Rank=  jsonObject.getString("rank");
                             Accuracy=  jsonObject.getString("accuracy");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

Comment: no i cannot find the solution through it please help me with right syntax to use, you can see the problem @Saurabh Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Use `GsonConverterFactory` to convert incoming json into model/pojo class

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:LATEST_VERSION'
```

Please go through following links 
[Retrofit Library Tutorial](https://tutorialwing.com/android-retrofit-library/)

[Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit)

Answer (score 0):

Use this link to convert your JSON into POJO with select options as selected in image below   [http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

You will get a POJO class for your response like this

```
public class Result {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;


/**
* 
* @return
* The id
*/
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
* 
* @param id
* The id
*/
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

then and use interface like this:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/level")
Call<Result> checkLevel(@Field("id") int id);
```

add the dependencies

```
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.+'
```

and call like this:

```
Call<Result> call = api.checkLevel(1);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
        response.body(); // have your all data
        int id =response.body().getId();
        String userName = response.body().getUsername();
        String level = response.body().getLevel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

to get the response in JSON don't use `addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` from Retrofit.